# Filtering through data in JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have access to some JSON data that has some headers that are irrevelant to me. When I access the JSON through my App, these extra 3 fields are showing up as blank entries(see image) How can I filter this data feed at the scope level to only get access to the data in the middle {}, bkev_name etc(list of 23 properties).

[image]

```
    .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state','$cordovaBluetoothSerial', '$window', '$location', function($scope, $http, $state, $cordovaBluetoothSerial, $window, $location) {
      $http.get('js/12137.json').success(function(data) {
       $scope.orders = data;
```

Comment: If `data` is the same as that JSON you have in the picture, couldn't you just do `$scope.orders = data.data`?

Comment: This then brings a list of the internal data(detail) in my order list(master), this is the data that should be shown on the detail page not on the order page  http://i.imgur.com/xTuBGR5.gif

Comment: You aren't making any sense. Simplify your question to **exactly** what you want to happen, **exactly** what's currently happening and what you have done to try and solve it. Also, please don't post pictures of code. Copy the code text into your problem. Only use images if you have a visual problem and the image helps explain that problem.

Comment: I assume you're using **ng-repeat** to create the list view.  set its model to an appropriate array, such as `$scope.orders = [ data.data ];`

Comment: @MikeC Pretty sure your first comment is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set its model to an appropriate array, such as

```
$scope.orders = [ data.data ];
```